# Exporting MYSQL table into excel

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I have some PHP script for export MYSQL table into Excel format, but I get some problem after the table have exported. The data which get from db just show only one row.

This the following script:

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("qdbase",$dbc) or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());

$sQuery = "SELECT id, Line, Model,Lot_no,
                  COUNT( Serial_number ) AS Qty,
                  SUM(S), SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C),
                  (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1) / COUNT(Serial_number) AS QP,
                  ROUND((SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1) / COUNT(Serial_number)*1000,2) AS PPM
            FROM  `inspection_report`";

$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or die();
$count = mysql_num_fields($rResult);

// fetch table header
$header = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       $header .= mysql_field_name($rResult, $i)."\t";
       }
// fetch data each row, store on tabular row data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rResult)){
       $line = '';
       foreach($row as $value){
              if(!isset($value) || $value == ""){
                     $value = "\t";
              }else{
                     $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                     $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                     }
              $line .= $value;
              }
       $data .= trim($line)."\n";
       $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);

if ($data == "") {
       $data = "\nno matching records found\n";
       }

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// output data
echo $header."\n".$data;
?>
```

beside that, how to make some border for this table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if i want to do : echo ""; which the correct place to
>   put it that cant make my script become
>   error?

If youre goign to do it as an html table then i would jsut output liek you normally right a table... for example you might do:

```
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or die();
$count = mysql_num_fields($rResult);

$html = '<table border="1"><thead><tr>%s</tr><thead><tbody>%s</tbody></table>';
$thead = '';
$tbody = '';
$line = '<tr>%s</tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){      
  $thead .= sprintf('<th>%s</th>',mysql_field_name($rResult, $i));
}


while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rResult))){
  $trow = '';

  foreach($row as $value){
   $trow .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value);
  }

  $tbody .= sprintf($line, $trow);

}


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

print sprintf($html, $thead, $tbody);
exit;
```

---

Youre only getting one row because youre using aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` clause. Try adding a `GROUP BY` on on something that ties each of these "entries" to a specific group like the `Lot_no` or whatever youre trying to report on.

As far as the border, you cant do that with `CSV` which although readbale by Excel, is not actually an `Excel` format file with all the extras like formatting for borders. To use things like formatting you need to output native Excel or an html table that can be loaded into excel. Take a look at [`phpexcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) if you need to do that.

Comment: if i want to do : echo "<table border=1>"; which the correct place to put it that cant make my script become error?

Comment: yah...i want to do like this.

Comment: +1 for identifying the problem, and for referencing PHPExcel for generating real Excel files rather than tab-separated value files masquerading as xls

Comment: @Mark: thanks for creating/cntributing to the library. I just used it recently and it helped me out. The only complaint I had form my limited usage was that the documentation want browseable online (at least not that i could find) and that when downloaded it was in Word format. Other than that its a GREAT project.

Comment: @prodigitalson - the documentation can currently only be seen online by accessing it through the "Source Code" tab. Word format is used because most people can read Word documents, even using Open Office. PHPDocs API documentatrion is available in the production release downloads. I'm in the process of extending the documentation at the moment, so if you have any ideas for improvement/alternative formats, feel free to suggest.

Comment: @Mark: The king of all formats... HTML. I like to browse documentation online (or hosted locally), not open a word processor. PDF is also preferable to Word/OO because pdf viewers are cheaper on resources (well other than Acrobat, but who uses Acrobat??? ;-) ). And PDF is just as ubiquitous as Word/OO. Were I you i would create all the docs in docbook and then automate building to html and pdf.  The docs themselves were fine though.

Comment: The potential drawback with other formats is the options available on codeplex... think other formats would have to be created by hand/converted externally rather than as part of the buoild process; plus increasing the size of the download... buyt I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually pulling anything else from the tables. You only have one query and it is pulling the header information. Run a sql statement like "select * from tableName" to get the rest and then do the while and for loop with that query. PHP/browsers do not normally work well ith items outside of programming languages, XML, and CSV. I would look more toward either one of those. XML is readable by the newer versions of excel (and openable in Internet Explorer in XML form), while csv is more widely used to share between different types of databases/spreadsheets. For an example of XML output goto http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/index.html and for CSV output you will have to use fputcsv() function on an array. For Examplle:

```
 $query = mysql_fetch_row($rResult);//the query of the table
             // use 'select * from table' to list everything
 $xls = fopen('file.csv', 'a'); //opens document for writing and attempts to create if file does not exist
 foreach ($list as $fields) {
      fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }
 fclose($xls); //always close the file when done
```

Both are dirty ways of exporting but work.

Comment: +1 for phpexcel, it's a pretty solid library for dealing with Excel docs in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

try this code it works for me :

```
<?php
$db_name     = "db_name";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_link     = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$table = "table_name";
function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else return 0;

  return $arr;
}

function query_whole_table($table, $value = '*'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}

$export_str = "";
$result = query_whole_table($table);

foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= implode(";",$record) . "\n";
}
// add time to fileName
$date = time(); 
file_put_contents($date.'_'.$table."_export.csv", $export_str);
?>
```